# Why am I getting stackoverflow?

Tags: java

```
public class SortAnimal
{
    public static Comparator<Animal> getAnimalTagComparator()
    {
        return getAnimalTagComparator();
    }

class getAnimalTagComparator implements Comparator<Animal> {

    @Override 
    public int compare(Animal o1, Animal o2) {
        return o1.getTag()-o2.getTag();         
    }
}
```

I have another file that generates an array and calls:

```
Comparator<Animal> getAnimalTagComparator = SortAnimal.getAnimalTagComparator();
```

Why am I getting stackoverflow on this line: return getAnimalTagComparator();

Comment: Why wouldn't you? What does that line do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAnimalTagComparator()` calls itself recursively infinite number of times (or at least until the stack overflows). That's causing a stack overflow.

You should use different names for your class and method, and change the method to something like :

```
public static Comparator<Animal> getAnimalTagComparator()
{
    return new AnimalTagComparator();
}
```

and change the class to `static class AnimalTagComparator`. (the static modifier is required because the `AnimalTagComparator` class is nested inside your `SortAnimal` class, and without making it static, you would need an enclosing instance of `SortAnimal` in order to create an isntance of `AnimalTagComparator`).

Comment: I just tried adding new and changing the name to something else but now I'm getting this error: When I try adding new I'm getting another error: No enclosing instance of type SortAnimal is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type SortAnimal (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of SortAnimal).

Comment: @AlldaRage See my edit - make your AnimalTagComparator class static and you wouldn't need an enclosing instance.

Answer (score 1):

Because your code is just calling itself (you are calling a recursive method).
As there is no termination of this calling, then you will eventually get a StackOverflow Error

```
public static Comparator<Animal> getAnimalTagComparator()
{
    return getAnimalTagComparator();  // yes this is THIS method
}
```

if you were wanting to call the other class you could do

```
public static Comparator<Animal> getAnimalTagComparator()
{
    return new getAnimalTagComparator();
}
```

Comment: Suggesting to change the name of the class to something more useful will be great.

Comment: When I try adding new I'm getting another error: No enclosing instance of type SortAnimal is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type SortAnimal (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of SortAnimal).

Comment: Why do you have this as an embedded class?  Try re-visting an Comparator example.